# Why textfield not catch text inside and don't add to database

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-android

When I press button with onSendClicked is not adding text from textfield. I don't know where not catching text. I guess is somewhere mistake with viewmodel, becouse viewmodel don't get new value.

```
fun AddBar(
    onSendClicked: () -> Unit
){
    Row(Modifier.padding(5.dp)) {
        var title by remember {
            mutableStateOf("")
        }
        TextField(
            value = title,
            onValueChange = { title = it }
        )
        IconButton(onClick = {
            onSendClicked()})
        {
            Icon(imageVector = Icons.Filled.ArrowForward, contentDescription = "Send Icon")
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MainScreen(
    basketViewModel: BasketViewModel,
){
   AddBar(onSendClicked = { basketViewModel.addToBasket() })

 }
```

And viewModel

```
    val id: MutableState<Int> = mutableStateOf(0)
    val title: MutableState<String> = mutableStateOf("")

    fun addToBasket(){
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val basket = Basket(
                title = title.value,
                isChecked = false
            )
            repository.addToBasket(basket = basket)
        }
    }
```

Help....

Answer (score 1):

You are never using the `title` state of the `ViewModel`. You are only updating the local `title`. For this to you have to stop using local title and just replace it with the `title` from viewModel. Something like that:

```kotlin
fun AddBar(
    title: MutableState<String>,
    onSendClicked: () -> Unit
){
    Row(Modifier.padding(5.dp)) {
        TextField(
            value = title.value,
            onValueChange = { title.value = it }
        )
        IconButton(onClick = {
            onSendClicked()})
        {
            Icon(imageVector = Icons.Filled.ArrowForward, contentDescription = "Send Icon")
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MainScreen(
    basketViewModel: BasketViewModel,
){
   AddBar(
      title = basketViewModel.title,
      onSendClicked = { basketViewModel.addToBasket() }
   )

 }
```

Comment: Not working, title from constractor is not used ( grey color ) and onValueChange in lambda "title = it" is incorrect

Comment: Updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

You define the title both in view model and your main screen. Use the one in your view model.

```
fun AddBar(
    title: String,
    onValueChange: (String) -> Unit,
    onSendClicked: () -> Unit
){
    Row(Modifier.padding(5.dp)) {
        TextField(
            value = title,
            onValueChange = { onValueChange(it) }
        )
 
        IconButton(
            onClick = { onSendClicked() }
        ) {
            Icon(
                imageVector = Icons.Filled.ArrowForward,
                contentDescription = "Send Icon"
            )
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MainScreen(
    basketViewModel: BasketViewModel,
){
    AddBar(
        title = basketViewModel.title,
        onValueChange = { basketViewModel.changeTitle(it) }
        onSendClicked = { basketViewModel.addToBasket() }
    )
}

class BasketViewModel : ViewModel() {
 
    var title by mutableStateOf("")
        private set

    fun changeTitle(value: String) {
        title = value
    }

    fun addToBasket(){
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val basket = Basket(
                title = title.value,
                isChecked = false
            )
            repository.addToBasket(basket = basket)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> This is how you create a textfield in StackOverflow:
> val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current
> EditNumberField(label = R.string.bill_amount, value = amountInput, onValueChange = { amountInput = it},  keyboardOptions =  KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number, imeAction = ImeAction.Next),keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(onNext ={focusManager.moveFocus(FocusDirection.Down)}))
> EditNumberField(label = R.string.how_was_the_service, value = tipInput, onValueChange = { tipInput = it}, keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number, imeAction = ImeAction.Done),keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(onDone ={focusManager.clearFocus()}))

> fun Topics(){LazyVerticalGrid(columns = GridCells.Fixed(2),
> verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.padding_small)),horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.padding_small)) modifier = Modifier.padding(dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.padding_small))){items(DataSource.topics) {topic -> TopicCard(topic) }}}

Comment: Please read the help on edit and format your code

Comment: Which can be found [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)